# Getting image and list to appear on the same line

Tags: html, css

This is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/FMfDM/1/

I can't seem to get my logo image to sit on the same line as my list, even if I put `display:inline` on the image.

Can anyone please tell me what is the proper approach to this, since using `float: right` is also making my list items appear in reverse order!

Comment: Hi, its customary on Stack to mark the FIRST right answer as the correct one, especially when later answers reference it?! Please note the time of my answer vs. the one marked as correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Cliff mentioned, you'll need to float the left img or anchor.

http://jsfiddle.net/scottmey/BKWrR/

```
#nav a, #nav img {
    float:left;
}
```

and consider:

```
#nav ul {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That will do it:

```
#nav img {float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1):

try `<ul style="display:inline;">`

Answer (score 1):

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kermani/FMfDM/2/)

html

```
    <nav id="nav">

  <ul>
      <a href="index.html"><img src="logo.png" id="logo"/></a>
     <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
     <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**and css**

```
* {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}


ul li{
  display: inline;
    float: right;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
    background:gold;
    width:80px;
    border:1px solid black;
    text-align:center;
}

#nav {padding-top: 30px;}
```

**you can change color and everything else what you like!**

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav id="nav">
  <a href="index.html"><img style="float:left" src="logo.png" id="logo"></a>
  <ul>
     <li><a href="features.html">Features</a></li>
     <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
     <li><a href="signup.html">Sign up</a></li>
     <li><a href="login.html">Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```